# "Can't edit this property from an override data-block" while adding driver

Tags: drivers, linked-data

I tried to add a driver to a custom property after library override.
And I checked the message, "Can't edit this property from an override data-block."
On the other hand, proxy allowed driver to be added to a custom property.
Why is this happening? Is this because library override is still in development?
I have attached a diagram of what I tried and a warning message below.
[image]
[image]

Comment: I guess you can't (yet). I hope this will be possible once the system is production-ready. However you can define the driver inside the base file and change the target object inside the work file... It has its limitations though

Answer (score 2):

In Blender 2.9 you can define the driver inside the source file and set your custom property with the "is library overridable".

[image]

Then you will be able, at least to animate and change the value for that driver through your custom property in your work file.